# Magento 2 customizable option stops my custom module working

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom module which added a phtml file just below the add to cart button. It works perfectly fine until I add a customizable option for the product. After adding customizable option, my phtml file not loading.
Here is my layout and phtml files.
Layout file at location `\app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="Custom_Module::css/embroideries.css" />
    <link src="Custom_Module::js/embroideries.js"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block class="Custom\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\Block\Index" name="embroideries" template="Custom_Module::catalog/product/view/embroideries.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
    
</body>
```

My phtml file:
 `app\code\PurpleCommerce\GenerateJson\view\frontend\templates\catalog\product\view\embroideries.phtml`

```
<?php
echo "loaded";
```

My Block class:
`\app\code\Custom\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\Block\Index.php`

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\Block;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{   
 

protected $_embroideries;
protected $_varFactory;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \PurpleCommerce\GenerateJson\Block\Index $embroideries,
    array $data = []
    
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    $this->_embroideries = $embroideries;
}
 


public function getCurrentProduct()
{
    return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
}
}
```

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved my block to the main page wrapper and all works :). In my `\app\code\vendor\modulename\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="main.content">
        <container name="product_view_extra" htmlTag="div">
            <block class="PurpleCommerce\Embroideries\Block\Catalog\Product\Block\Index" name="catalog.product.view.extra" as="embroideries" template="PurpleCommerce_Embroideries::catalog/product/view/embroideries.phtml" cacheable="false">
            </block>
        </container>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reindex and c:f?

Comment: I tried already..no luck :(